# Use jQuery to set image's box-shadow from multiple images

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, image-gallery, css

I am using a jQuery gallery that displays a large image in the middle and a smaller image either side of it (http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx) and want to add some effects to it. The gallery takes as many images  in a container div, class "gallery" as is supplied and from that produces the gallery. It is not possible to add individual classes or ID's to the images due to the way they are generated and I am struggling to find a way to use jQuery to select the middle going into the middle.

What I am trying to achieve is setting box-shadow on the image as it moves into the middle so that it looks like it is coming out of the screen and then removing the shadow once it has transition to the outer space again. I can use jQuery to set the same shadow on all images but this is not what I want and could be achieved without jQuery.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like that plugin does not expose event hooks for you and it doesn't add any classes to the currently centered image. All that is bad, it means that you have to alter the code of the plugin to achieve this. Here's a link to the script's readable source: http://www.meadmiracle.com/scripts/jquery.slidingGallery-1.2.js... the documentation is extremely limited.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I've just been looking at the source code and whilst I have a basic idea of what it is doing and how, it's a bit beyond my grasp so I might just go for having all the images with shadow, or the same amount of, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the selected image, when enlarged, has a z-index applied to it.  You could use jQuery to find that element and test its z-index value.  Something like this might work:

```
if($('.gallery img').css('z-index') > 0)) {
   // do something like add toggle a class
}
```